# Bernoulli trials - Average?

Tags: combinatorics

Grocery Max satisfies 97 people out of 100.
a) [Solved] Find the probability that 7 applications of 12 will be satisfied. 
b) [?] What is the average amount of satisfied people in Max?

I don't get it. Is it P(1) * 1 + P(2) * 2 + ...P(12) * 12?

Comment: Yes, the "average" is the same as the "mean value" which is what you have.

Comment: P(1) * 1 + P(2) * 2 + ...P(12) * 12? Btw, wouldn't that result in 0.97?...

Comment: I don't see the data for the problem.  You need the average number of total people in Max or something like it for b