# Simple Probabilities

Tags: combinatorics

The 1992 US Senate was composed of 57 Democrats and 43 Republicans. Of the Democrats, 38 served in
the military, whereas 28 of the republicans had seen military service. If a senator selected at random had
served in the military, what is the probability that he was Republican? Note: No congresswoman had served
in the military.

I am thinking it should be A = 57 - 38 = 19; B = 43 - 28 = 15; (A or B) = 34

answer = B / (A or B) = 15/34 = 44.1%, but the answer is ~42%

Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you subtracting?  That gets you the number that did not serve.  You have $38+28=66$ who served, $28$ of whom are Republican.  The chance is then $\frac {28}{66} $

Comment: Oh. My bad. Thank you! I am struggling with one more, can you check it out? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275256/bernoulli-trials-average?noredirect=1#comment4680047_2275256